# how to show cocos2d in xcode while creating new project?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have installed cocos 2d templates using below document:
http://www.i2links.net/i2/showthread.php?t=26284

Its installed perfectly.

But when i am going to create new project at that time cocos2d templates not display in xcode.

I dont know what is the problem.

Please advice me for this query.

Thanks in advance

Edit: I am using XCODE 4

Comment: Obviously if the templates don't show up when you create a new project, the templates were not "installed perfectly".

Answer (score 0):

try using **./install-templates.sh -f -u** this command

Answer (score 0):

on my mac the templates only installed correctly when I used admin rights. You can do this by running the install-templates script with sudo in front of it.

```
sudo ./install-templates.sh -f
```

Here is a nice explanation of different ways to install the templates. When you run them look at the output in the terminal. It should tell you that the installation was successfull.